# Can I load .dsv files from S3 to Redshift / SQL Workbench, or convert them to another file type in S3?

Tags: file-transfer, sql, redshift

I have a lot of files in .dsv format from a client, and I need to get them into SQL Workbench. I have previously only loaded .txt and .csv before and cannot find documentation.

Is it possible to copy .dsv files, and if so, how?

Is it possible to convert the file type, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

DSV, also called
[Delimiter-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values)
is exactly the same as CSV, apart perhaps for having a different delimiter or quote
characters.

As you know already how to import CSV, you should have no difficulty with DSV.

Here are some helpful references:

- [IBM DSV formats](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPFMY_1.3.5/com.ibm.scala.doc/extend/iwa_extend_dsvtoolkitDSVFormats.html)
- [How to Import Data into SQL Tables](https://data36.com/how-to-import-data-into-sql-tables/)
  See the section "Data import method #2: When you want to import data from a .csv file",
  regarding the use of the COPY command.
- [How can I move data from spreadsheet to a database through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151188/how-can-i-move-data-from-spreadsheet-to-a-database-through-sql)
  Gives an example for using [WbImport](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-import.html).